# Power BI Matrix Visualisation compare columns

Tags: matrix, powerbi, visualization, dax, kpi

I am trying to take the following data set (example [data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72xD2.jpg))

```
|PAF TYPE             |dbvalue               |volume      |date_run     |
|---------------------+----------------------+------------+-------------|
|BFPO                 |BFPO                  |604         |19 March 2020|
|Care Of              |Care Of               |710         |19 March 2020|
|BFPO                 |BFPO                  |1000        |23 March 2020|
|Care Of              |Care Of               |610         |23 March 2020|
|BFPO                 |BFPO                  |12000       |30 March 2020|
|Care Of              |Care Of               |800         |30 March 2020|
```

And visualise this in PowerBi as a matrix, displaying only the latest 3 run dates. Such as

```
|PAF TYPE         |19 MARCH 2020     |23 MARCH 2020    |30 MARCH 2020
|-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------
|BFPO             |604               |1000             |1200
|Care Of          |710               |610              |800
```

[image: visualition]

What I am struggling to do is to calculate the change between each of these dates dynamically.  e.g. increases, decreases and no change.  There are two ways I would ideally like to this 1) numeric value (+ or -) or b) kpi (arrows)

Any thoughts, help would be much appreciated.

Hoping the images are shown here.

Comment: please import the content of the images as code to your comment to avoid broken links in the future, gl

Comment: Thanke Eduardo.  I've added these as best able, hopefully this will help with understanding the query.